# What is the complement probability of the following event?

Tags: probability

For a graph $G=(V, E)$, we have
$$P\left(\begin{array}{l} \text{there exists a subgraph } A \text{ with} \\
\text{at most $k$ vertices and Euclidean} \\
\text{diameter at least } Ck \end{array} \right)\ge p
$$
for some constants $C>0$.

Question: What is the complement of the above probability? Is it
$$P\left(\begin{array}{l}
\text{for any subgraphs } A \text{ with at} \\
\text{most $k$ vertices and Euclidean} \\
\text{diameter at least } Ck \end{array} \right) \le 1-p\text{?}$$

Comment: Either "there exists *no* subgraph $A$ with $\le k$ vertices and diameter $\ge Ck$," or equivalently "every subgraph $A$ has either $> k$ vertices or diameter $< Ck$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seems actually to be, not about the complementary probability, but about the complementary event. The complementary probability is $1-p.$

The event is
\begin{align}
& \text{there exists a subgraph } A \text{ such that} \\[5pt]
& \left( \begin{array}{l}
A \text{ has at most $k$ vertices} \\
\underline{\textbf{and}} \text{ } A \text{ has Euclidean diameter at least } Ck
\end{array} \right).
\end{align}

The complementary event is
\begin{align}
& \text{there does } \underline{\textbf{not}} \text{ exist a subgraph } A \text{ such that} \\[5pt]
& \left( \begin{array}{l}
A \text{ has at most $k$ vertices} \\
\underline{\textbf{and}} \text{ } A \text{ has Euclidean diameter at least } Ck
\end{array} \right).
\end{align}
This is equivalent to
\begin{align}
\text{for every subgraph } A, \\[5pt]
\text{it is } \underline{\textbf{not}} \text{ true that } & \left( \begin{array}{l}
A \text{ has at most $k$ vertices} \\
\underline{\textbf{and}} \\ A \text{ has Euclidean} \\
\text{diameter at least } Ck
\end{array} \right).
\end{align}
By de Morgan's law this becomes
\begin{align}
& \text{for every subgraph } A \\[5pt]
& \left( \begin{array}{l}
A \text{ has more than $k$ vertices} \\
\underline{\textbf{or}} \\ A \text{ has Euclidean} \\
\text{diameter less than } Ck
\end{array} \right).
\end{align}
(And of course this "or" is inclusive, i.e. it means one or the other or both.)

Comment: Thanks for the very nice answer! So here in the last part, "or" means the union of these two events, right?

Comment: Also, so can we say $P( \mbox{ for every subgraph } A \mbox{ with less than } k \mbox{ vertices and  A has Euclidean diameter less than } Ck)\le 1-p$

Comment: @Hermi : I'd say that without the "and": For every subgraph $A$ with no more than $k$ vertices, $A$ has Euclidean diameter less than $Ck.$"